# Python parsing stdin much faster than C++

Tags: c++, stdout, stdio

I have a python function which I was hoping to translate into C++ to try and gain some extra speed (as it will be used to parse >100GB files). I am very inexperienced with C++ and was horrified to find my C++ function running much slower after my basic translation. Any pointers as to why this is, or what I can do to improve my C++ code would be much appreciated.

Script overview: the function reads stdin from another program, checks each line for any substring matches, and prints each line to stdout

> **Python function:**
>
> ```python
> def find_tagPy(conditions):
>     # conditions e.g. ['TTAT', 'TAT'] etc   
>     for line in stdin:
>         # Check conditionss against this line
>         l = line.split("\t")
>
>         if l[0][0] == "@":
>             stdout.write(line)
>             continue
>
>         FLAG = int(l[1])
>
>         if 1 & FLAG:  # Read has a pair
>             for bases in conditions:
>                 if bases in l[9]:
>                     ADD_MATE = 1
>                     stdout.write(line)
>                     break  # stop looking
> ```

**C++ function:**

```c++
void find_tagCpp (vector<string> conditions) {
    cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    string line;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        vector<string> l;
        boost::split(l, line, boost::is_any_of("\t"), boost::token_compress_on);

        if (l[0][0] == '@') {
            cout << line << "\n";
            continue;
        }

        int FLAG = stoi(l[1]);
        int pair_FLAG = 1;

        if (pair_FLAG & FLAG) {  // Read has a pair
            for (int i=0; i < conditions.size(); i++) {  // If bases in SEQ
                if (l[9].find(conditions[i]) != string::npos) {
                    cout << line << "\n";
                    break;  // Stop looking
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of a stdin line is:

FCC2CCMACXX:4:1105:10758:14389# 81  chrM    1   32  10S90M  =   16151   16062   CATCACGATGGATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTTTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCGATAGCATTG    bbb^Wcbbbbccbbbcbccbba]WQG^bbcdcb_`^_`c_^`ccdddeeeeeffggggiiiiihiiiiihiiihihiiiihghhiihgfgfgeeeeebbb    NM:i:1  AS:i:85 XS:i:65 RG:Z:1_DB31

On my machine the python function takes 1.97 s and the C++ function takes 11.05 s (file size around 25 mb, but this includes processing with upstream and downstream tools)

**EDIT:**

I've found a bottleneck in boost::split which is a bit suprising:

Python:

```
for i in range(100000):
    l = line.split("\t")
```

C++:

```
for (int i=0; i < 100000; i++) {
    vector<string> l;
    boost::split(l, line, boost::is_any_of("\t"), boost::token_compress_on);
}
```

Python = 0.0325 s

C++ = 1.245 s

However my file is only 156,980 lines, so this cant be the whole problem.

Comment: Looking at the code, I would put my money on `std::string` performance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: plus1 for compiler flags. From my experience `-O0 -g3` code can even be slower than C# code.

Comment: Guessing debug build for C++.

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of why the C++ code runs slower than the Python code?  Or are you seeking a review of the C++ code to improve it in anyway it can be improved?

Comment: Use a performance profiler (like the one baked into Visual Studio) and *see for yourself* what the slow part of your code is.

Comment: I just wanted to know why this code is slower. I was hoping a quick translation would give me a speed boost, but I guess I need to learn something about compiler flags...

Comment: If you're using gcc or compatible, add -O2 when compiling. If you're using Visual Studio, make sure that you're compiling in Release and that optimizations are turned on (Projetc properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Optimization > Optimization should be /O2)

Comment: vector isn't very fast either

Comment: @ChrisMaes How is exactly is `vector` "not very fast"?

Comment: With pythons object representation model I always assumed c++ would offer better performance when using native types and STL containers etc

Comment: @kezzos There are some trivial inefficiencies in your code, but I would mainly look into `boost::split` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7930796/boosttokenizer-vs-boostsplit

Comment: Thanks Let_Me_Be, ill get to it

Comment: And btw. test the first character before you split :-D

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: I noticed in codes I tried to optimize that most of the time using a fixed array and indices was faster than using vector and iterators. This **might** be a cause..

Comment: @ChrisMaes There is no difference between indices and iterators with `vector`. This is the direct results of how `X[Y]` is defined in C and C++. If you are trying to say that dynamic allocation is slow, then yes, it is and there is no way around dynamic allocation if you need it.

Comment: Is it possible that Python is optimizing the expression `bases in l[9]` into a finite-state machine that can search for any of the bases in time approximately linear to the length of the haystack string?  The C++ code is explicitly checking each base individually, which is also approximately linear in the length of the haystack string, but has a higher constant factor proportional to the number of bases.

Comment: @IanAuld: Please stop trying to shoehorn questions into CR. If this question is off-topic here, then vote to close it for *proper, listed reasons*. You can *advise* that a question might be a good CR fit, but the first rule of voting to close a post is that it has to *actually be off-topic here*. For example, this question might be *too broad*. At which point you vote to close it as such, advise the OP that it might be a better fit for CR (check their on-topic help info first) and flag the post to ask a moderator to migrate it. But don't abuse the custom close vote messages for this.

Comment: @IanAuld: last but not least, CR is for *holistic code improvement*; just because someone asks why code is slow doesn't mean they want a full break-down of their working code and how to improve it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This question fits in to the criteria listed in [What questions are on-topic for this site?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the Code Review help center. I was under the impression that if an OP has working code they would like to improve the Code Review was the place to get that done.

Comment: I would prefer to know why it is slow so in future I can better use my time coding in python rather than re-writing things in c++ just to see if it will go faster.

Comment: @IanAuld: but that doesn't make a question *off topic here*. Don't close a question just because it is on-topic on another site as well. There is no reason to send someone to another site just because it might work there *too*.

Comment: How did we allow ourselves to make so many comments? Shouldn't we just had one comment, insisting that the OP tell us their compiler and the compiler flags they used? And we should have left a downvote until the OP delivered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my original code is not amenable to testing, so I thought I would refactor it here, and discuss what I have found.
I turned on compiler optimisations using the -Ofast (fastest, aggressive optimisations, Apple LLVM 6.1) as suggested, and for comparison Python is 2.7.10.

**Python function**

```python
import time

def fun(line):
    l = line.split(" ", 10)
    if 'TTAGGG' in l[9]:
        pass

line = "FCC2CCMACXX:4:1105:10758:14389# 81 chrM 1 32 10S90M = 16151 16062 CATCACGATGGATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTTTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCTTAGGGGATAGCATTG bbb^Wcbbbbccbbbcbccbba]WQG^bbcdcb_^_c_^`ccdddeeeeeffggggiiiiihiiiiihiiihihiiiihghhiihgfgfgeeeeebbb NM:i:1 AS:i:85 XS:i:65 RG:Z:1_DB31"

time0 = time.time()
for i in range(100000):
    fun(line)

print time.time() - time0
```

**C++ function**

```c++
void fun(string* line, string* substring) {
    vector<string> l;
    boost::split(l, *line, boost::is_any_of(" "));
    if (l[9].find(*substring) != string::npos) {
        // Do nothing
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string line = "FCC2CCMACXX:4:1105:10758:14389# 81 chrM 1 32 10S90M = 16151 16062 CATCACGATGGATCACAGGTCTATCACCCTATTAACCACTCACGGGAGCTTTCCATGCATTTGGTATTTTCGTCTGGGGGGTGTGCACGCTTAGGGGATAGCATTG bbb^Wcbbbbccbbbcbccbba]WQG^bbcdcb_^_c_^`ccdddeeeeeffggggiiiiihiiiiihiiihihiiiihghhiihgfgfgeeeeebbb NM:i:1 AS:i:85 XS:i:65 RG:Z:1_DB31";
    string substring = "TTAGGG";
    boost::timer t;

    for (int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        fun(&line, &substring);
    }

    cout << t.elapsed() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine I now time the c++ function at 205 ms and the python function at 66 ms. Interestingly, now almost the entire runtime is taken up by the boost::split function.

If I get rid of this function and use string.find to search the whole line (not quite what I wanted though):

```
if ((*line).find(*substring) != string::npos) {
    // Do nothing
}
```

The c++ runtime is reduced to about <1 ms! So it appears boost::split was the problem all alone. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The split copies the pieces into new strings.  This is slow and you do not need them.  Instead search the line for the start of the piece you want ( 10th ) and then call find starting from there.

Comment: The documentation for boost::split implies that it's merely making pairs of iterators rather than copying the strings.  Perhaps a subsequent operation is forcing C++ to instantiate a string.

Comment: I think pythons split should do the same thing

Comment: "Each part is copied and added as a new element to the output container. " http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/split_id820181.html

Comment: If `split` is making a pair of interators from each token, then perhaps `l` should be a `vector<pair<iterator, iterator>>` (where `iterator` could even be `const char *`, instead of `vector<string>`.

Comment: The docs, quoted in my previous comment, tells that split is NOT making a pair of iterators.  Please read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with some optimization

C++ function:

```
void find_tagCpp (vector<string> conditions) {
    cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    string line;
    vector<string> l;
    while (getline(cin, line)) {
        l.clear();
        boost::split(l, line, boost::is_any_of("\t"), boost::token_compress_on);

        if (l[0][0] == '@') {
            cout << line << "\n";
            continue;
        }

        int FLAG = stoi(l[1]);
        int pair_FLAG = 1;

        if (pair_FLAG & FLAG) {  // Read has a pair
            for (int i=0; i < conditions.size(); i++) {  // If bases in SEQ
                if (l[9].find(conditions[i]) != string::npos) {
                    printf("%s\n", line.c_str());
                    break;  // Stop looking
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```